# How to eliminate this loop from my Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

My goal is to change an order three matrix, to an order two matrix simply (perhaps with one line of code) Any idea?

```
A = rand(256, 256, 3);
B = zeros(256, 256);


for i = 1: size(A, 1)
    for j = 1 : size(A, 2)
        B(i,j) = max(A(i,j, :));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
B = max(A, [], 3);
```